# How to prove the binomial identity $\binom{n}{r - 1} + 2\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r + 1} = \binom{n + 2}{r + 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

> Prove that $\dbinom{n}{r - 1} + 2\dbinom{n}{r} + \dbinom{n}{r + 1} = \dbinom{n + 2}{r + 1}$.

I've tried manipulating both sides with $\dbinom{n}{r}$ factored out but I'm stuck. Any help?
[image]

Comment: The fraction $\frac{r+1}{n-r}$ on the left hand side is incorrect. Double-check your work, then divide by $\binom{n}r$ and the remaining fractions will be equal.

Comment: Isn't nC(r-1) = nCr * (r+1)/(n-r)? Like nC(r+1) = nCr * (n-r)/(r+1)?

Comment: Please type your question rather posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**  Apply [Pascal's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)
$$\binom{m}{k} = \binom{m - 1}{k} + \binom{m - 1}{k - 1}$$
to the right-hand side, then apply it to each of the resulting terms.

Comment: Okay, this made it surprisingly easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a pile of $n$ green beads, and $2$ blue beads.   Now the way to select $r+1$ of those $n+2$ beads can be counted as:

$$\binom 22\binom{n}{r-1}+\binom 21\binom{n}r+\binom 20\binom n{r+1}$$

---

But wait, $\dbinom {n+2}{r+1}$ is *also* the count of ways to select $r+1$ items from $n+2$.   ....

Answer (score 2):

Consider the coefficient of $x^{r+1}$ in $(1+x)^{n+2}$. This is $\binom{n+2}{r+1}$. On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{n+2} &= (1+x)^{n}(1+x)^2 \\
&= (1+x)^n(1+2x+x^2)
\end{align*}
The coefficient of $x^{r+1}$ on the right hand side is 
$$\binom{n}{r-1} + 2\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Vandermonde's Identity, 
$$\begin{align}
\binom n{r-1}+2\binom nr+\binom n{r+1}
&=\sum_{i=0}^2 \binom 2{2-i} \binom n{r-1+i}\\
&=\binom {n+2}{r+1}\end{align}$$